# Disappearing Reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation

The past couple of days, I have had something going on with my reputation. Every now and then, it will go down a few points without warning. I checked and there are no downvotes cast, or anything else that would remove rep. Why is this happening? Is it caused by edited posts being deleting, or something like that?

Comment: Tip: don't polish turds. (i.e. suggest edits to bad posts that are going to be deleted.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Taking a look, it looks like you are losing rep due to posts being deleted - it likely says -2 (removed) if you look at the full reputation breakdown in your profile.

When the posts are deleted, any associated rep is also removed.

Comment: As to why it's -2 specifically, OP would've had an approved suggested edit on the post

Comment: Probably the edits.  I remember seeing the OP's name in many edit suggestions.